# Customer portal (posts as checklist)

Tags: metabox, user-roles

This is a pretty difficult one:

We are extending our services for our customers. Our customers have to do some things like, buy a apple developer account, generate google analytics key, buy a google play account etc. I would love to setup standard posts and mark them as todo list for specific users.

I've already setup a service custom post type with a couple of tutorials as posts but would like to add a metabox with registered users and mark a post as 'todo' and 'done'. When a user logs in I like fetch these and show them as seperate lists.

Does anyone have a clue how to get started? I'm a designer myself and know a little bit of PHP but not hardcore..

Comment: Like [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/cleverness-to-do-list/)?

Comment: Hi Toscho, awesome plugin but I need it for the front-end and less advanced.

Comment: You can control who sees what. Adding a front-end mask shouldn’t be so hard.

Comment: Thanks Toscho, but it's not really what I'm looking for. I have a few default posts 'how to buy a apple developer account' and the best for us to simply click next to a name if this is a post for them and if they completed it already.